# Locally bounded additive function is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is additive, i.e. $T(X_1+X_2)=T(X_1)+T(X_2)$.
$T$ is locally bounded. Prove that $T$ is a linear transformation.

I know there is a relation between boundedness, convexity and scalar multiplicity. But not sure where to start or how to tie things together.

Comment: Can you show it for $k = m = 1$? The general case follows from that, but $k = m = 1$ is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show that $T(rX)=rT(X)$ for $r\in\Bbb Q$.
2. Use (1) together with local boundedness at $0$ to show continuity at $0$.
3. Continuity at any point.
4. Use (1) and (3) to conclude.