# Additive function, locally bounded at zero

Tags: functions, continuity

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is additive and locally bounded at zero then $f(x) = ax, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Because $f$ is additive we know that $f(x) = ax, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Also, because $f$ is locally bounded at zero we know that $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x \in (-\delta,\delta) \Rightarrow$ $|f| \leq M, \ M \in \mathbb{R}$.

How, can I use both of them to show continuity at zero and therefore continuity at $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks for the help and\or any advice.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008938/locally-bounded-additive-function-is-linear

Comment: Thank you both of you for your replies !!!